# How to stop services in spec file

Tags: rpm

I have this spec file that will install numerous rpm packages such as apache, mysql, etc.
I'm new to building rpms and I did looked at the Fedora documentation but I did not find the answer to my question.

How do I add commands in my spec file so that if I do a:

```
rpm -e 
yum erase
```

it will stop services that wasn't stopped during yum erase/rpm-e?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be relevant to this case, but remember that if you will upgrade your RPM, rpm will install the new version and then remove the old one, so after upgrade the services will be down. To be on the safe side, do:

```
%preun
if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
then
    service https stop
    # or what ever you want
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in spec file preun which runs before package is uninstalled:

```
%preun
service https stop
# or what ever you want
```